# Unable to uninstall node.js from my windows 10

Tags: node.js, uninstallation

[image]Getting this issue while iam uninstalling node.js from programs and features.

Comment: That’s unfortunate; thanks for letting people know. If you’re requesting *help* you may want to provide details.

Comment: can you upload your error's snapshot?

Comment: i added the image above can u plz help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running `npm cache clean --force`

Then clean these directories

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
- C:\Program Files\Nodejs
- C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
- C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
- C:\Users{User}.npmrc (and possibly check for that without the . prefix too)
- C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-*

Remove it from environment variables
Try rebooting

---

**or you can read this blog for some different methods [here](http://www.uninstallhelps.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-by-joyent-inc.html)**